# Push textview onto new line if too long

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Not too sure how to word this but if you look at my picture below the blue of Victoria disappears off the screen but i'd like to to start a new line so you can clearly see the whole thing.

[image]

Heres my xml for for each list component. I have 5 textviews which are situated to the right of the preceding one, how can I pickup when one is too long for the line and move to another line?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tube_stop_graphic1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="25sp"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tube_stop_graphic2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="25sp"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_below="@id/tube_stop_graphic1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tube_stop_graphic3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="25sp"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_below="@id/tube_stop_graphic2"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tube_stop_name"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="BLABLA"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tube_stop_graphic1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tube_stop_distance"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
            android:text="BLABLA"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tube_stop_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tube_line1"
            style="@style/Tube_Stop_TextView"
            android:text="Overgound"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tube_stop_graphic1"
            android:layout_below="@id/tube_stop_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tube_line2"
            style="@style/Tube_Stop_TextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tube_line1"
            android:layout_below="@id/tube_stop_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tube_line3"
            style="@style/Tube_Stop_TextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tube_line2"
            android:layout_below="@id/tube_stop_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tube_line4"
            style="@style/Tube_Stop_TextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tube_line3"
            android:layout_below="@id/tube_stop_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tube_line5"
            style="@style/Tube_Stop_TextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tube_line4"
            android:layout_below="@id/tube_stop_name"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and the style for each of them

```
<style name="Tube_Stop_TextView">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">5sp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5sp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">5sp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">5sp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_square</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: have you tried to set android:singleLine to that textView?

Comment: I tried both that and the inputType="Text" and it puts it onto one line but extends it off the screen! I'd like to be pushed onto a new line if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you wrap all your textviews in a gridview. Because your first TextView is having long text here. Gridview will push any view which is out of available width to a new row.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if you had some kind of example of how to do it that'd be real helpful